# Question about Microposts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am study Ruby on Rails and here is my question. I am making a new application in Rails and having some problems,

Here is my code

`rails _5.2.3_ new toy_app
rails generate scaffold Micropost content:text user_id:integer
rails db:migrate
rails server`

They said that I should try to reach by this URL

https://rails-tutorial-c9-mhartl-c9.io/micropost/new but nothing happen.

Here is my problem, the server said
`HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>`

I know my question is just a little bit stupid but could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post routes, by running, 'rake routes', second, are you running your server locally? if so, try localhost:3000/micropost/new

Comment: Could you show logs? I mean text in console, when you run 'rails server'

Comment: What does rake routes from your terminal output, please post

Comment: @user2012677: thank you for your comment. I solved my problem by your comment, by the way all of your comment helped me so much.